# Python: How to scrape the string 7.7872 in <span class='pos'><span class='arr_ud arrow_u5'> </span>&nbsp;7.7872</span>

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following line and extract the value of 7.7872, how to I make it work?

```
<span class='pos'><span class='arr_ud arrow_u5'> </span>&nbsp;7.7872</span>
```

I tried the following code but there is some blank string which I cannot get ride off:

```
for a in soupUSD.find_all("span", attrs={"class":"pos"})[0]:
    print(a)
```

I have the following result:

```
<span class='arr_ud arrow_u5'> </span>&nbsp;7.7872
```

Any way I can just find the text of 7.7872 only?

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

spam = "<span class='pos'><span class='arr_ud arrow_u5'> </span>&nbsp;7.7872</span>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(spam, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find('span', {'class':'pos'})
print(' '.join(span.stripped_strings))
```

output

```
7.7872
```

Comment: I solved by using this line instead: (but yours work as well)
for a in soupUSD.find_all("span", attrs={"class":"pos"})[0].stripped_strings:

Comment: well, this will yield generator: `<generator object Tag.stripped_strings at 0x7f25ea928c00>` but if it makes you happy... And if you convert it to e.g. list - `['7.7872']`

Answer (score 0):

Since at the same level of your target string there are other tags as well, the `.string` attribute doesn't detect the string (in this case). So you can loop over the tag content and look for string, instances `NavigableString`, then cast it to string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

spam = "<span class='pos'><span class='arr_ud arrow_u5'> </span>&nbsp;7.7872</span>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(spam, 'lxml')
span = soup.find('span', class_='pos')

nr = ''.join([str(string).strip() for string in span.contents if isinstance(string, NavigableString)])

print(nr)
# 7.7872
```

Answer (score 0):

Using core python lib (ElementTree)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


dtd = '''<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [
            <!ENTITY nbsp ' '>
            ]>'''

html = '''<span class='pos'><span class='arr_ud arrow_u5'> </span>&nbsp;7.7872</span>'''
root = ET.fromstring(dtd + html)
print(list(root)[0].tail)
```

output

```
 7.7872
```